# Need to change $1 value to $1 variable in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script which is using a environment variable.

The environment variable has $1 set in the value. When I am using the env variable in the script, I need to use the $1 as the parameter passed from the script arguments.

Example:

```
export EXPORT_VAR="-DmyVariable=\$1"
```

In a shell script (myScript.sh), I have used the above env variable like below.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java $EXPORT_VAR com.myProject.myJob "$@"
```

I am running the script as follows:

```
./myScript.sh var1 var2
```

I want the following command to be executed

```
exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -DmyVariable=var1 com.myProject.myJob "var1 var2"
```

Please advise.

---

$1 is just an example. The environment variable can have $2....$N. The same variable should be assigned to -DmyVariable while execution

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest refactoring your script so you can pass in the variable as an option.

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
 -e | --export-variable )
   myvar=$2
   shift 2 ;;
esac
exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -DmyVariable="$myvar" com.myProject.myJob "$myvar" "$@"
```

You might want to change the script so it requires the `-e` option or specifies a reasonable default value.  This is just to give you an idea of how to refactor the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your script as :

```
#!/bin/bash

exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -DmyVariable=$1 com.myProject.myJob "$1 $2"
```

Comment: The $1 variable is not fixed. There are many case where it might be $2 or $3.